# Convolution matrix for diagonal motion blur

Tags: filter, matrix, convolution, motion-blur

I know my question is not really a programming question but it came out of programming need. Does anyone happen to know the convolution matrix for diagonal motion blur. 3x3, 4x4 or 5x5 are all good.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is 5x5:

```
   0.22222   0.27778   0.22222   0.05556   0.00000
   0.27778   0.44444   0.44444   0.22222   0.05556
   0.22222   0.44444   0.55556   0.44444   0.22222
   0.05556   0.22222   0.44444   0.44444   0.27778
   0.00000   0.05556   0.22222   0.27778   0.22222
```

I basically drew a diagonal line, and then blurred it a little.

Comment: What about Zoom Motion blur? http://docs.gimp.org/2.6/en/plug-in-mblur.html I will have to create a new filter for each pixel?