# I need motion blur algorithms

Tags: image-processing, gimp

I need motion blur algorithms for a small image
editing app. Can you point me to some resources,
books or papers or maybe code examples?

Which resources does GIMP use for this math?

Thanks

Comment: An example can be seen in this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602988/convolution-matrix-for-diagonal-motion-blur) question.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the Gimp Blur-Motion source is [here](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gimp/tree/plug-ins/common/blur-motion.c?id=GIMP_2_8_0).

Comment: Hmm really it is just a convolution with a mask? I thought it is much more complex? What about Zoom and Radial blurs? http://docs.gimp.org/2.6/en/plug-in-mblur.html You calculate a different mask for each pixel?